# What could cause this randomly appearing error inside jQuery itself?

Tags: jquery, javascript

I'm pounding my head against this. Once every 5-10 times I reload my app, I get a bizarre error originating inside jQuery. I try adding breakpoints inside the non-compressed version of jQuery to try to back out from the error, but Chrome never stops for them, instead *always* skipping ahead to the error.

I'm using jQuery 1.7.2, but this error also occurs in versions 1.7 and 1.6.1.

In my javascript app, I call this line of code:

```
this.element.find('.banner-btn')
```

Where `this.element` is a jQuery object. There is no reason this should cause a problem, and 9 times out of 10 there is no problem. But randomly something breaks, and then every time that line of code is called the result is some variant of this stack trace:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined
makeArrayjquery-1.7.2.js:4858
Sizzlejquery-1.7.2.js:5110
jQuery.fn.extend.findjquery-1.7.2.js:5432
```

In fact, *any* time after this breaks that I call $.fn.find I get this error. I have tried all kinds of things, I've been reading the jQuery source, and I can't get anywhere on this. Anybody have any idea where to go with nailing this down?

### Update: further down the rabbit hole

I've chased this further into the jQuery library, and found where the error first pops up. Kind of.

To keep track of DOM traversal, jQuery uses the [pushStack](http://www.learningjquery.com/2011/12/using-jquerys-pushstack-for-reusable-dom-traversing-methods) method. This is called in the jQuery.fn.find method, and is *supposed* to return a jQuery object. And it normally does -- but when something snaps inside jQuery, this function only returns a regular object, with no jQuery goodies. This causes an error down the line.

Okay, here is the first little bit of source for pushStack, defined on line 241 of jquery-1.7.2.js:

```
// Take an array of elements and push it onto the stack
// (returning the new matched element set)
pushStack: function( elems, name, selector ) {
if(window._debug_jQuery_pushStack) { debugger }
    // Build a new jQuery matched element set
    var ret = this.constructor();

// ---- the function continues, but this is enough for us ----
```

The bit where `var ret = this.constructor();` is where the jQuery goodies are supposed to be added. In this case, they're not. Somehow `this` has been corrupted into a regular object, not jQuery. So now my question is: how do I find the cause of this corruption? A difficulty is that this only occurs once out of 10 or 20 times my application loads, and appears to be completely random.

Comment: could you provide maybe a larger portion of code? jsfiddle or something?

Comment: Can you recreate your error using jsfiddle.net? Which browsers, besides chrome, are you able to recreate this error in?

Comment: That's what's tricky: this code is embedded in the middle of a large application. Something in that large application is abusing jQuery such that it has internal errors -- but only 1 in 10 times -- and I don't know how to narrow it down. I've tried putting breakpoints in strategic places inside jQuery, but they never stop execution.

I haven't tried other browsers yet.

Thanks!

Comment: Put a breakpoint on this line `makeArrayjquery-1.7.2.js:4858` then look at the callstack and see what's triggering it.

Comment: I just updated the question with some more details pinning down where the error is coming from. Now the question is what on earth is causing the error...

Comment: @jpadvo did you make any progress solving this? we're hitting the same problem.

Comment: @JamesCrowley Kind of - I fixed the symptom without ever discovering the cause. I had three or four setIntervals running in different places in my code, and I think they were somehow colliding inside the browser. I consolidated them with a simple jQuery plugin that had *one* setInterval, that would call any methods I registered with it (let me know if you want more details or the plugin code itself). I stopped seeing the error after this. I'm pretty sure it was a browser bug relating to setInterval, but I don't actually know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not in your code, but in Chrome itself -- see [bug #125148](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=125148).  The current workaround is to change pushStack as follows:

```
pushStack: function( elems, name, selector ) {
    // Build a new jQuery matched element set
    var ret = this.constructor();

    // temporary workaround for chrome issue #125148
    // http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=125148
    if (!(ret instanceof jQuery.fn.init)) {
        console.log("applying pushStack fix");
        ret = new jQuery.fn.init();
    }

    // ... snip ...
```

Also, see [this related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314992/chrome-sometimes-calls-incorrect-constructor) question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's jquery, but something in your code, and jquery is responding to it. The culprit in my mind is the "undefined." Something's being manipulated by jquery (perhaps a var that's intended to be an array) inside your application that's causing this to happen. I've seen that recently when using backbone.js and using jquery for DOM operations. Turns out that occasionally, my app code was not properly setting a var and jquery threw an error when that happened.

So my advice is that if you know at least the general area within your sequence where the error is occurring, look at your app code and see if everything there is kosher; that all your vars are getting assigned. It's possible that there's an edge case where a var is not being assigned and it's a simple matter of placing a conditional around that area in case it's not.

Comment: Thanks. I've got chrome set to pause on errors so I can examine the state of everything down the trace, and all my variables are set properly. Moreover, running $('a') and other basic stuff results in the same error. Something inside jQuery got corrupted somehow -- possibly caused by my code, but golly gee whiz if I can find anything that would have done it...

Comment: Yeah, it's a tough one for sure. You might also want to send console messages with the values of your various vars - I know, painful, but sometimes that's the only way to catch those edge cases.

Comment: I just ran into this issue and agree with Brendan - look at your code and be sure the error isn't there. In my case, I was calling a DOM method on a jQuery set (of one object), so adding jQuery's ".get(0)" did the trick. E.g., instead of "$('a').href.match(…)" I changed it to "$('a').get(0).href.match(…)".