# Chrome sometimes calls incorrect constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

We have a web site that uses extensively jQuery and it works fine in Firefox and IE. However in Chrome, we are getting frequently (and semi-randomly) `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined` (also other jQuery methods appear in place of `apply`).

We managed to track down the problem to jQuery method `pushStack()`.

Original source code (jQuery 1.7.1):

```
// Take an array of elements and push it onto the stack
// (returning the new matched element set)
pushStack: function( elems, name, selector ) {
   // Build a new jQuery matched element set
   var ret = this.constructor();

   // (etc.)
}
```

Instrumented code:

```
pushStack: function( elems, name, selector ) {
   if (!(this instanceof jQuery.fn.init)) throw this;

   // Build a new jQuery matched element set
   var ret = this.constructor();

   if (!(ret instanceof jQuery.fn.init)) {
          console.log("pushStack>this: " + this.constructor);
          console.log("pushStack>ret: " + ret.constructor);
          throw ret;
   }

   // (etc.)
}
```

In most cases `pushStack()` runs correctly. However sometimes Chrome constructs an object of type `Object` instead of `jQuery.fn.init`. Console output:

```
pushStack>this: function ( selector, context ) {
    // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
    return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
    }
pushStack>ret: function Object() { [native code] }
Uncaught #<Object>
```

Did anybody encounter similar problem? Is it a (known) bug of Chrome?

**Update**

I managed to simplify our page, so that it could be loaded on its own. I filled [bug in Chromium project](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=125148) project, the page for reproducing the issue is attached there.

Comment: Could you narrow down the use case? It sounds like the common `console.log.apply` context problem.

Comment: @David Thank you for your comment. What do you mean by ```console.log.apply``` context problem? The problem happens also when using original jQuery without instrumentation.

Comment: @MiroslavBajtoš Have you applied the workaround suggested in the Chromium project?

Comment: @davidzarlengo Yes, I am the author of that workaround.

Comment: Oh, well, in that case, thank you! So far, it's working for us as well.

Comment: @davidzarlengo You are welcome, I am glad that the fix works for you too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The responses in Chromium bug tracker seem to confirm that this is a bug of Chrome browser.

The workaround solution is to "fix" `pushStack()` function in jQuery:

```
// Take an array of elements and push it onto the stack
// (returning the new matched element set)
pushStack: function( elems, name, selector ) {
   // Build a new jQuery matched element set
   var ret = this.constructor();

   // Workaround for Chrome bug
   if ((this instanceof jQuery.fn.init) && !(ret instanceof jQuery.fn.init)) {
       // console.log("applying pushStack fix");
       ret = new jQuery.fn.init();
   }

   // etc.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround! Is there any conceivable way this workaround could be applied without having to amend the jquery source file (eg in code following the inclusion of the jquery minified file from the Google CDN)? This would mean including the jquery source in our build which we're not currently doing.

Comment: @centralscru Look at the response below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10727909/69868

Comment: Awesome, don't know how I missed that!

Answer (score 5):

Here is an "unobtrusive" solution (for example, if you're pulling jQuery from a CDN).  Save this in a .js file and include it after pulling in jQuery.

```
(function ($) {
    var pushStackOrig, pushStackChrome;

    pushStackOrig = $.fn.pushStack;

    pushStackChrome = function ( elems, name, selector ) {
        // Build a new jQuery matched element set

        // Invoke the correct constructor directly when the bug manifests in Chrome.
        //var ret = this.constructor();
        var ret = new jQuery.fn.init(); 

        if ( jQuery.isArray( elems ) ) {
            push.apply( ret, elems );

        } else {
            jQuery.merge( ret, elems );
        }

        // Add the old object onto the stack (as a reference)
        ret.prevObject = this;

        ret.context = this.context;

        if ( name === "find" ) {
            ret.selector = this.selector + ( this.selector ? " " : "" ) + selector;
        } else if ( name ) {
            ret.selector = this.selector + "." + name + "(" + selector + ")";
        }

        // Return the newly-formed element set
        return ret;
    };

    $.fn.pushStack = function (elems, name, selector) {
        var ret;

        try {
            ret = pushStackOrig.call(this, elems, name, selector);
            return ret;
        } 
        catch (e) {
            if (e instanceof TypeError) {
                if (!(ret instanceof jQuery.fn.init)) {
                    ret = pushStackChrome.call(this, elems, name, selector);
                    return ret;
                }
            }

            throw e;
        }
    };

}).call(this, jQuery);
```