# jQuery + jQuery Mobile + Chrome 20

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, jquery-mobile

We are experiencing a strange problem after updating Google Chrome to the latest version, can someone help us? we are getting out of ideas.

We have several .aspx pages in wich we include jquery core (1.7.1) and jquery mobile (1.1.0) and some jqm plugins. everything worked perfectly until we updated google chrome... we started getting totaly **random** errors like:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined"
>   "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'jqmData' of undefined"

In Firefox, IE9/10 and Safari everything works properly.
The exception is beeing thrown by jquery mobile in the initializePage function.
we created a basic page (structure and some basic elements)... still no luck.

We found this similar problem but is from 2010. 
http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/JDKZxXsQZiE/sdW9-g1rxYs

Any ideas/sugestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could it be about that v8 bug : http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=125148 ?

if so, see the workaround there : [Chrome sometimes calls incorrect constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314992/chrome-sometimes-calls-incorrect-constructor/10725004#10725004)

Comment: tks :D 
we are going to give it a try!